# Cannot upload image to FTP via PHP

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I am currently have some issues trying to get my php upload form to work. I am getting this error... Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

The ftp connection if working fine i'm just unsure as to what could be stopping the upload.

This is the php...

```
$target_dir = "photos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["photo"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Photos (image_name, thumb, photo, photo_alt) VALUES 
('$_POST[image_name]', '$_POST[thumb]', '$_POST[photo]', '$_POST[photo_alt]')");

    if (array_key_exists ('check_submit', $_POST )) 

    if (!$res) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
```

and the html....

```
    <input type ="hidden" value="1" name="check_submit" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>

     Please Enter Name: <input type ="text" name="image_name" /> <br />

     Tags: <input type ="text" name="photo_alt" /> <br />

     thumb  <input type="file" name="thumb" /><br/>

     image  <input type="file" name="photo" /><br/>

    <input type ="submit" name"Submit" /><br />

</form>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It might be a permission issue; does your script have write access to /photos/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enctype attribute should be in form tag itself

```
<form action="photos-upload.php" name="Myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: If that were the issue it would have output "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."

Comment: @Ja͢ck However, without supplying a correct value for the `enctype` attribute in the form tag, the upload could not be occurred.

Comment: I mean that he should fix this issue first and then looks for any other reasons.

Comment: Guess you didn't understand my point then; what I'm saying is that this couldn't have been the issue judging by the error that was mentioned, regardless of what you say is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did work and the file is now going into the ftp folder. The only issue im having now is that the file name is no longer being inserted into the database, any ideas? No errors and I know the sql query works because if i remove the image upload stuff the name goes into the database, new code edited above. Thanks

Comment: Try to use `sprintf` in your `mysql_query` string.

Comment: If you mean the file name i.e some/path/file.jpg, you have not supply it in the sql query!

Comment: I see what you mean, Is there a way I can get the name dynamically from the file uploaded? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are able to insert `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']`